# need to adapt a windows cmd script to work in bash

Tags: bash, cmd

i am currently using this script to move some files and run some other commands:

---

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "src=sourcePath"
set "dst=destinationPath"
set "search=1080p"

for /r "%src%" %%F in (*%search%*) do (
  set "full=%%~fF"
  set "name=%%~nxF"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    copy "!full!" "%dst%\!name:%search%=!"
    endlocal
)
REM call your batch script here to process the copied files
```

---

can anyone help my adapt it to bash so that i can run it in linux?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? - [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362/143302)

Comment: `cp /sourcePath/*1080p* /destinationPath/.`?

Comment: the script above removes the 1080p from the file name. your command wont remove the 1080p when it copies

Comment: currently im here:

for file in $(find ./ -type f -name *_1080p*.*); do echo $file; done

this just returns the list of files i need.... i need to copy the file while removing the 1080p then run another command on that new file

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact format of all your file names its harder but you could try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(find ./ -type f -name _1080p.*)

for file in ${files[@]} ; do
  new_file=$( echo $file | sed -e 's/_1080p//' )
  cp $file $new_file
  ## add further commands on $new_file here.
done
```

Can be improved by adding a regular expressions to the find command, and adjust the sed line to rename the files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you,

`file2=$(echo $file | sed -e "s/[1080p]//g")`

`cp /sourcepath/$file destinationpath/$file2`

should work within your for statement.